# Objective-C beginner; what do I need to create a countdown timer?

Tags: objective-c

I've just started learning Obj-C. As an alternative to the usual maths examples, I thought I'd try and create a countdown timer - perhaps one that could time multiple events.

Have looked at NSTimer but am having trouble working it out - especially which method to use.

I've tried to find some source code - but so far it's all Cocoa stuff which is even more difficult to work out.

If someone could point me in the right direction - that would be great.

If this is too ambitious for a newbie - please let me know and perhaps suggest a project that I can get stuck into.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you start using timers, it's important to understand how run loops in Cocoa work.  Try reading Apple's documentation on [run loop management](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html).  There's an example of using NSTimer in there; hopefully by the time you get to it, you'll understand why things work the way they do.

For an even simpler example, check out [this tutorial](http://www.osxfaq.com/Tutorials/cocoa/index5.ws) which creates a timer inside the `main` function.

The second Cocoa app I wrote was a simple timer.  Of course, 8 years later I'm still maintaining it...